# Xcode 12: Compiling for iOS 10.0, but module 'RxSwift' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 12.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, rx-swift

I just updated Xcode to the latest version, and the project is no longer compiling. I removed everything and tried to rebuild pods but ended up having the same issue this issue:

> [x]
> /Users/alouanemed/Projects/App-iOS/Pods/_Prebuild/Moya/Sources/RxMoya/MoyaProvider+Rx.swift:2:8:
> compiling for iOS 10.0, but module 'RxSwift' has a minimum deployment
> target of iOS 12.0:
> /Users/alouanemed/Projects/App-iOS/Pods/build/Release-iphoneos/RxSwift/RxSwift.framework/Modules/RxSwift.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule
>
> import RxSwift
> ^

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With cocoapods and Xcode 12, you currently need to set your Pods' deployment targets in a so-called "post-install hook".

Try adding this to the end of your Podfile:

```
deployment_target = '12.0'

post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = deployment_target
            end
        end
        project.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = deployment_target
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Wow was tearing my hair out with this one. I'm using Xcode 13.4.1 and this worked for me. Any idea why we need to add this?

Comment: I just chalked this up to a cocoapods idiosyncrasy and have since moved on to use SPM.

Comment: Ya makes sense. I’ve switched to SPM for new projects. Will eventually do the same for older projects.

Answer (score 8):

Just to people who may end up in the same case as me. The reason of this error was that I was using the `beta` channel. After switching to the `stable` channel, I ran

```
cd ios/
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
cd ..
flutter clean
```

And, I removed the `Podfile` and the `Podfile.lock`. Then, I built the project again and it worked!

Comment: It's like 3rd time I'm finding this answer and it totally saves my ass. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are tying to import a version of `RxSwift` that has already set its minimum deployment target to iOS 12.0 while your project itself is still on iOS 10.0.

This should not be related to Xcode or the Xcode update.

If you can post your Podfile we can verify this.

Comment: My deployment target is 12

Answer (score 1):

You need to change minimum deployment target, you can change it from `Xcode` like this (here i changed it to 11, in your case you need to change it to 12):

[image]

Comment: P.s make sure your Module Build setting - Deployment Target - is set to a bigger ios version than the minimum. Only the module you are building