# Compiling for iOS 9.0, but module 'BSGridCollectionViewLayout' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to build flutter app on IOS and i get this error:

Compiling for iOS 9.0, but module 'BSGridCollectionViewLayout' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 10.0

Tried: [Xcode 12: Compiling for iOS 10.0, but module 'RxSwift' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 12.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967156/xcode-12-compiling-for-ios-10-0-but-module-rxswift-has-a-minimum-deployment) didn't work

[image: Target target]

[image: Runner target]

How Can I fix this ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your screen snapshot is showing the deployment target for the app, but you have to look at the deployment target of the dependency. E.g. if using Cocoapods:

[image]

By default, it uses the deployment version of the pod. But if you validate your project settings, it will try to change the deployment version, so I would uncheck that option during the settings validation process.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your project directory just go to **ios > open Podfile** then,

```
platform :ios, '10.0' // Change this 9.0 to 10.0
```

This will fix your error.