# A lot of warnings because of Coccaopods with Firebase on M1 Mac

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

When I use Cocoapods to set up Firebase on my M1 Mac and I use Rosetta on the Terminal everything works fine. But I got tons of warnings. When I fix them everything works good but I don't know if I should do it. Can someone explain what these warnings mean and what I should do with them? The most are the same like this one:
`Anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here`

[image]

Comment: What versions of Firebase and Xcode are you using? Re: the deployment target issues, check out [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967156/xcode-12-compiling-for-ios-10-0-but-module-rxswift-has-a-minimum-deployment/64954635#64954635)

Comment: If you click on the "update to recommended settings" at the top of the image it will likely fix most of those version issues